# Loading a scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a "Start Game" button

```
public static bool GameIsStart;
     public void changeCamera ()
     {
             if (GameIsStart == true)
                 return;

             GameIsStart = true;
             SceneManager.LoadScene ("Game");
     }
}
```

``
There is a script that I added to the Prefabs

```
    public GameObject [] gameobject;
    private bool gameobject_IS_Spawn;
    private float RandomPositionforX;
    private int RandomObjects;

    private void Update ()
    {
        if (StartGame.GameIsStart &&! gameobject_IS_Spawn)
        {
            StartCoroutine (Spawngameobject ());
            gameobject_IS_Spawn = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Spawngameobject ()

    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (StartGame.GameIsStart)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.3f);
                RandomPositionforX = Random.Range (-2.28f, 2.28f);
                RandomObjects = Random.Range (0, gameobject.Length);
                Instantiate (gameobject [RandomObjects], new Vector2 (RandomPositionforX, 24f), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a button on the "Game" scene to access the preview

```
public void ChangeScene ()
{
SceneManager.LoadScene ("preview");
}
}
```

I click on the button, the "Preview" scene is loaded, but the "Start game" button does not work.

If I put in the "Preview" button SceneManager.LoadScene ("Game")
then I restart the scene ("Game") and everything works.
But if SceneManager.LoadScene ("Preview") but the buttons don't work.
When switching between scenes, is it necessary to stop Coroutine
How can this problem be corrected?

Comment: Do you mean C#? Unity is not C-based.

Comment: "Other hay?"? What the hay?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it's a bit harder to find where the problem is coming from.
The only thing that is coming to my mind is that it may be something related with how the scene is stored and loaded after.

According to the [Scene Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) Documentation, you could save the scene1 in a variable and keep the DontDestroyOnLoad(scene1) on its awake method, then add something like:
`Scene scene2 = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();  SceneManager.LoadScene(scene1);` To the button that reloads the previous scene.